# php add 1 line to existing index.php

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, strpos

I have some websites and I want to add a new code just after <?php
I wrote this code but not works:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$dir = __DIR__;
$index = $dir.'/index.php';

if (is_file($index)) {
    $content = file_get_contents($index);
    if (strpos($content, 'validator') === false) {
        str_replace('<?php', '<?php require_once \'path/validator.php\';', $content);
        
        //Write the index:
        $write = fopen($index,"w");
        fwrite($write,$content);
        fclose($write);
    }
    
    //Check again:
    $content = file_get_contents($index);
    if (strpos($content, 'validator') === true) {
        echo "Line added successfuly";
        unlink($dir.'/install.php');
    } else {
        echo "Line not added";
    }
}
?>
```

How can I do this?
Thanks...

Comment: What do you want to do with the code? If you can explain the problem that you are trying to solve, it will be easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos()` never returns `true`. It either returns a numeric index or `false`.

So change the second check to

```
if (strpos($content, 'validator') !== false)
```

By the way, you can use `file_put_contents()` to write the file in one step, just as you use `file_get_contents()` to read it.